# Using StartActivityForResult and onResultReceive i'm getting an error. is there something wrong?

Tags: android, android-activity

The activity that gives the result:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (Login.length()==0 || Senha.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getLogin.this, "Por favor preencha login e senha!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return;
}
Bundle gGuy = new Bundle();
gGuy.putStringArray("Login", new String[] {Login.getText().toString(), Senha.getText().toString()});
//gGuy.putString("Login", Login.getText().toString());
//gGuy.putString("Senha", Senha.getText().toString());
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("bGuy", gGuy);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

}

And the result receiver:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 555) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bGuy = data.getExtras();
            Info = bGuy.getStringArray("Login");
            doMe = new Syncro();
            doMe.execute();
        }
        else {
            doLog.doWarning("Erro ao obter login da intent result!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat error:

```
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=555, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.ibssistemas.pda/com.ibssistemas.pda.doSync}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at com.ibssistemas.pda.doSync$Syncro.onPreExecute(doSync.java:79)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at com.ibssistemas.pda.doSync.onActivityResult(doSync.java:126)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
08-10 15:13:30.038: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5489):     ... 11 more
```

**SOLVED:** Changed '`putExtra`' to '`putExtras`'
Result: 
       `i.putExtras(gGuy);`

Comment: Where does requestCode get set to 555? And on what line is the error?

Comment: Please paste the error u get in logcat , code seems alright

Comment: The requestCode is set when i call the activity with: startActivityForResult(i, 555); and the error happens between the two activities, not in a line. thx. Logcat error being pasted up in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem at this line in your code :

```
 Info = bGuy.getStringArray("Login");
```

var has no name.

But your problem might come from the way you use your bundle in the finishing activity.
Try

```
if( login.getText() == null || Senha.getText() == null )
{
  //Toast and return
}//if

Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle gGuy = i.getExtras();

gGuy.putStringArray("Login", new String[] {Login.getText().toString(), Senha.getText().toString()});
//gGuy.putString("Login", Login.getText().toString());
//gGuy.putString("Senha", Senha.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

Then you can get your array back in OnActivityResult (please add @Override annotation) in the way you already did it.

And please, read this about [naming conventions in java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Regards,
 sTéphane

Comment: Actually it does no work yet, it gets an error at gGuy.putStringArray("Login", new String[] {Login.getText().toString(),            Senha.getText().toString()});

Comment: You are getting NPE, maybe some of the getText()s is returning null. Do some testing for null or length == 0 ;

Answer (score 0):

`Info = bGuy.getStringArray("Login");`

Тhis is the faulty line. Instantiate it correctly.

Something like:

`String[] Info = bGuy.getStringArray("Login");`

Comment: What is confusing about info is that variable names in java should start by lowercase letters, whereas classes/interfaces/enums start by uppercase letters.